# How to ensure no repeating datas when use django?

Tags: python, mysql, django

### background

I aim at overing a project which is made up of django and celery.

And I  code two tasks which would sipder from two differnt web and save some data to database —— mysql.

As before, I do just one task, and I use `update_or_create` shows enough.

But when I want to do more task in different workers ,and all of them may save data to database, and what's more, they may save the same data at the same time.

### question

- How can I ensure different tasks running in different worker makeing no repeating data  when all of them try to save the same data?

  I know a django API is `select_for_update` which would set a lock in database. But when I reading the documentions,  it similar means, would select,if exist,update. But I want to select,if exist,update,else create. It would more be like `update_or_create`,but this API may not use a lock?

Comment: I'd suggest you either reorganize the data passed to the task (have a task only dealing with even `ID`s and the other with odd `ID`s, for instance) or use a global block (Redis comes to mind) Without code examples, there's no much else I can say...

Comment: Hi. Explain how googling your bullet/question with your tags does not answer your question. The general principle is for concurrent processes to access the database each from with a (possibly implicit) ('serialized' isolation level) transaction. Which might or might not involve (possibly implicit) locks. But the details matter. Please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: @BorrajaX I use the django orm,so,I try to use the queryset api to complite it. If I use redis, it means I should make the data in database go to redis when I run the server? each time would be not easy?I thinked so.

Comment: @philipxy Could you explain it anthor way which is easy English?I try to translate it into chinese, I just a little understand that , I may should have a good use in the lock of databse itself?

Comment: @BorrajaX Codes may not be necessarily? Just two process will add data to table and I try to ensure the data insert into table not be repeating? The logci now I know is, check exists or not,and insert or not.But may two process check and add at the same time?`update_or_create` is the check in django not in database.I try to explain it ,if something I explain bad,tell me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### about sorry

May the user anwered my question before had give me the right answer, but I did not get what they means.

### what I choose

Finally I use the redis lock to ensure no repeating data.

The logic just below:

when I get the data,I try to use 'set(key,value.nx=True,ex=60)' to get a lock from redis.

If the answer is True,I would try to use the django queryqpi 'update_or_create()'.

If not,I did nothing and return True.

It make the burst problem like a single process.